# Смена фото в профиле пользователя

Tags: php, html, база-данных

Я начинающий в разроботке сайтов, сечас я делаю личный кабинет пользователя. У меня возникла проблема с реализацией смены фото у пользователя.

Мне нужно чтобы по нажатию на кнопку открывалось окно проводника, человек выбирал фото и оно загружалось в бд, а потом при заходе в профиль фото выгружалось на страницу

Мне нужно понять как сделать загрузку фото в бд и как его выгружать из бд на php.

Comment: обычно картинки сохраняют в файловой системе, а в БД хранят путь к ним.

Comment: как тогда сохранять картинки в определенную дерикторию загруженные пользователем?

Comment: Меня интерисует функция загрузки

Comment: на тему загрузки файлов на сервер вы можете найти сотни статей и документации. Когда прочитаете и не будет получаться, тогда и придете тут вопрос задавать. Тут помогает проблему решать, а не теоретические основы рассказывают.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку на счет загрузки файлов на хостинг и записи в бд пути к ней, очень помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML форма:

```
 <form action="/accept.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <label for="file">Прикрепить файл:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    <input value="Отправить" type="submit">
</form>
```

Прием файла в accept.php:

```
$uploadfile = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], './' . $uploadfile)) {
    echo "Файл успешно загружен.\n";
}
```

[Источник с информацией по передаче файлов](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Для сохранения файла рекомендую создать какое-то хранилище на сервере и кидать данные в по генерированному пути, чтобы избежать дублирования файлов. Пример кода как это можно реализовать:

```
/**
 * Расчитать новый путь в хранилище
 * 
 * @param string $storagePath
 * @param string $originalPath
 * @param boolean $saveOriginalFileName
 */
protected function calculatePath($storagePath, $originalPath, $saveOriginalFileName = false)
{
    $path = $this->calculateMiddlePath($storagePath, $originalPath);
    if (!file_exists($path)) {
        mkdir($path, 0777, true);
    }
    return $path  . '/' . $this->calculateFileName($originalPath, $saveOriginalFileName);
}

/**
 * Сгенерировать путь до файла
 * 
 * @param string $storagePath
 * @param string $originalPath
 */
private function calculateMiddlePath($storagePath, $originalPath)
{
    $pathMid = str_split(md5($originalPath . strtotime('now')), 4);
    $pathMid = implode('/', $pathMid);
    return $storagePath . $pathMid;
}

/**
 * Сгенерировать новое имя файла
 * 
 * @param string $originalPath
 * @param bool $saveOriginalFileName
 */
private function calculateFileName($originalPath, $saveOriginalFileName)
{
    if ($saveOriginalFileName) {
        return basename($originalPath);
    }
    return md5($originalPath) . '.' . pathinfo($originalPath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
}
```

Как вам уже подсказали в комментариях, хранить файлы в базе данных - не лучшая идея. Достаточно сохранить сгененированный путь.

P.S Не стоит увлекаться с генерацией длинного пути)